# How to define static folder path in nodejs multer image upload

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

I am setting static path but getting error : "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\dashboard new - Copy\uploads\2019-11-28T08:11:09.164Z1564660431900.jpg'"

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({  destination: function(req, file, cb) { let dest = path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads'); cb(null, dest);  }, filename: function(req, file, cb) {    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);  }});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {    cb(null, true);  } else {    cb(null, false);  }};

const upload = multer({  storage: storage,  limits: {    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5  }, fileFilter: fileFilter});

router.post("/", upload.single('productImage'), async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    cosole.log('hi');
    const product = new Product({
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price,
      productImage: req.file.path 
    });
    const saveImage = await product.save();
    console.log(saveImage)
    res.json(saveImage);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.json(error);
}

});
```

How to do this?

Comment: I am not sure , either it will work or not, if you are using express then also try to serve static folder like this `app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'your-folder-path')))` or `app.use(express.static('public'))` something like that ,

Comment: I think you watch the video of "Academind" right? me too!
I think when we join the path the format "../../upload" not make work you have to pass the right path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to provide the destination folder as a key and value, something like this(below)

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

You can check out the full multer documentations here 
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html